# trig function Composition issues

Tags: trigonometry, function-and-relation-composition

How do you do this problem? I made a triangle but I don't know what to do after that. I looked at other questions similar to this but its not very well explained to me

$$\sin^{-1}⁡(\tan⁡-\fracπ4)$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** $\tan (-\frac{\pi}{4})=-1$